# Creating an X11 frame in mit-scheme + scmutils

Tags: mit-scheme, sicm

I am working through the book Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics, which requires writing scheme code in mit-scheme for its exercises. I've installed scmutils, the scheme library provided with the book, and when I launch mit-scheme, the following items are listed:

```
Release 10.1.10
Microcode 15.3
Runtime 15.7
SF 4.41
LIAR/x86-64 4.118
SOS 1.8
XML 1.0
Edwin 3.117
X11 1.3
X11-Screen 1.0
ScmUtils Mechanics.Summer 2019
```

This seems to suggest that X11 support is enabled. However when I use the `frame` command to try and create a window for a plot,
`(frame 0 :pi/2 0 5)`
I get the error:

```
;Could not find plugin: "x11"
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1
```

This is on Linux with X11, with mit-scheme installed through the package manager (pacman) and scmutils downloaded from the book/course website.

Moreover, some other commands from scmutils that involve invoking X-windows, like `show-expression` (that generates DVI output from an input math expression and launches XDVI) work fine.

The [install guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Unix-Installation.html) for mit-scheme says I need libx11-dev (or equivalent) installed if I want support for X11 graphics, but I downloaded the binary package from the repositories and I [can't tell if it comes with X11 support](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/mit-scheme/).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The version of `mit-scheme` available in the Arch Linux repositories does not come bundled with the plugin `x11` for X11 support, and it wasn't straightforward to add it manually.

Instead I downloaded the source from gnu.org and compiled it manually, then reinstalled scmutils on top for the SICM-specific features.